# Inputing text into TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an name `EditText` and it is annoying trying to remove the original text which is **"Enter your name"** from the `EditText` and was wondering how do you still have the **"Enter your name"** in the `EditText` but you dont have to delete it before the `EditText` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/..."
android:hint="Enter your name" />
```

You can refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint for more details

Answer (score 0):

You could use
`android:hint="Enter your name"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use hint attribute for this

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editTextId"
android:layout_width="200dip"
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:hint="Enter your name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Java or XML?, you need to explain better.

java:

```
public class Tramites extends Activity
{
    EditText e;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity);

         e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
         e.setText("hello");
    }
}
```

In XML:
check @TechnoBlahble answer

Answer (score 0):

Set the hint in your xml.

> android:hint="Enter your name"

Answer (score 0):

android:hint="Enter your name"
/>

Hint tag is used to show a message to user for a respective component.